# Does the 'Review' view update itself, or do I have to manually refresh the page?

Tags: support, review-page

Almost every time I go to see if anything is in the Review queue, there is absolutely nothing there.  At first, I attributed this to a team of ninjas that devour the review queue before I can ever see it (read: I shrugged), but I recently reviewed my first item and now interest is piqued again:

> Does the review 'tab' update itself automatically (ala 'An edit has been made to this post; click here to load'), or does this page have to be refreshed to pull in the fresh queue?

This is actually pretty annoying when working on a slow or otherwise painfully unreliable internet connection.

Comment: You are actually right about ninjas. Look at the history and stats. It's been months since I saw three items on any of those categories

Comment: My history is rather short (the only entry being today's), but stats show that there have been 33 reviews so far today.  Unfortunately, there is no facility to visualize this data over time.  So about them ninjas... I believe they may even be named.  ;)

Comment: Could be a feature request, too, after a bit of rewriting.

Comment: I'm guessing I would make this feature request on meta.SO?

Comment: @SeanAllred: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132985/live-updates-for-review-pages

Comment: @MartinSchröder Nice find.  I'll have to star this question and see what happens, but for some reason I remember that 'a new review interface' has already been released...?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152388/168273 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148784/real-time-updates-for-new-review-tasks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to refresh yourself – or install a browser addon, what does it for you *(update: builtin function in Opera)*.

---

*To answer the question in comment:*

I am a happy user of Firefox and can only say something about this, but for a start the search keywords for addons of other browsers should be “automatic tab reload” or “automatic tab refresh”. I found two nice blog posts, as well: [How to Auto Refresh Pages in Chrome, Firefox and Opera](http://www.guidingtech.com/12491/auto-refresh-pages-chrome-firefox-opera/) and [How to Auto Reload tabs in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome & Opera](http://www.tecflap.com/2013/01/12/auto-reload-tabs-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-opera/).

For Firefox the most popular specialised addon is [“ReloadEvery”](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/reloadevery/), another similar one seems to be [“Tab Auto Reload”](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-auto-reload/). But I myself use the more general aimed addon [“Tab Mix Plus”](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/), where the reload function is only one part of -  and there may be similar addons including this feature.

Comment: Do you know of any such browser add-on?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the new bar at the top will display a real-time notifier to the left of `review` (on the right).  It's not exactly the functionality that was sought after here, but it's close enough.

Comment: It's almost real-time and it seems to work only for suggested edits.